# Listview not show last item properly in scroll view

Tags: android, listview, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to implement listview inside scrollview or nestedscroll view but my list dose not visible last item properly .

please help me. how to visible all item properly

here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/electronic_TV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/no_data_find"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rltop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvadver"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="ADVERTISEMENT"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_viewfliper"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvadver"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                    <ViewFlipper
                        android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="130dp">

                    </ViewFlipper>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/fashionLV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvmsg"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"></ListView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code

```
 commanAdapter = new CommanAdapter(getActivity(), commanModelArrayList);
                            fashionLV.setAdapter(commanAdapter);
                            GeneralFunction.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(fashionLV);
```

GeneralFunction code:

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ArrayAdapter listAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
```

Comment: Add bottom margin ==15dp to litsview

Comment: its not good answer , because while i added margin bottom last item again not visible . but listview hold spacing from bottom

Comment: Did you provide custom height to listview or it's row?

Comment: listview height =wrap_content and row height=wrap_content

Comment: You put android:layout_weight="1" in listview so you have to change 
listview height =wrap_content =="0dp".

Comment: i tried but yet not working

Comment: For future me: Add padding bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "ListView" and "ScrollView" objects together is not recommended.

You should use different views in same adapter. For example;

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        MyListItem currentItem = myList.get(position);
        LayoutInflater Inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (currentItem.getListItemType() == "Description") { 
                rowView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.descriptionlayout, null);
                TextView tvDesc= (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvAccountType);
                tvDesc.setText("Desc");
        } else if (currentAccountItem.getListItemType() == "ListItem") {
                rowView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
               ...
        }
    }
```

You should add "ListItemType" property to your list object type. And check this property in `getView()` method and inflate different layouts.
In your case, you  can create new layout for your `LinearLayout`. And insert an object to your list for this row. And set ListItemType. and check this property and inflate this layout on `getView()`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` inside `NestedScrollView` creates lot of problems and `ListView` is *not*  recommended to use instead go for `RecyclerView`, you have to change the Adapter accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You add your *own* footer view in your `listview` by using list view methods.

It will shows after all the elements of `listView`.